# Group items in a set nicely

Tags: java, list, class, collections, set

Say like I have a set of classes: mine are a `Set < CourseListing >`

Some sample results of the `CourseListing` look like:

```
Number    Name            Product
TRN-001   Sample Name1    prod1
TRN-001   Sample Name1    prod2
TRN-001   Sample Name1    prod3
TRN-002   Sample Name2    prod1
TRN-003   Sample Name3    prod1
```

How can I get the products from TRN-001 to be grouped together into one field (ie a comma separated String)? It should then look like below:

```
Number    Name            Product
TRN-001   Sample Name1    prod1, prod2, prod3
TRN-002   Sample Name2    prod1
TRN-003   Sample Name3    prod1
```

Below is a sample of the `CourseListing` Class:

```
public class CourseListing{
    private String Number, Name, Product;
    public CourseListing(){
    }
//getters and setters;
}
```

I'm using a `List < CourseListing >`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your TRN numbers are identifiers, so why don't you use a map instead of a List?

When a new product has to be added:

- if the code does not exist add the entry `(CourseListing.getTNR, CourseListing)`
- if it exists, modify your existing CourseListing.

Answer (score 0):

here is how I would go about it, note it may not be the best solution but it would group them just like you explain based on the COurseListing number.
1. create a separate class as your object class for your first list(really a POJO

```
public class CourseListing {
    private String number;    
    private String Name;  
    private String product;
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

1. create a second class objects or use the existing one like above. Now you have tow objects for each group.

   CourseListing CourseListingNotGrouped = new CourseListing();
                CourseListing CourseListingGrouped = new CourseListing();
2. Loop through your first list and add it to your second list of objects when number=TRN-001.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over collection and filter the all `CourseListing` which `Number` eq `TRN-001`.

```
List<CourseListing> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
for(CourseListing c:courseListingList){
    if(c.getNumber().equals("TRN-001"))
       tempList.add(c);
}
```

and also you can use  -

[q-Link](https://code.google.com/p/q-link/) is a Java collection manipulation library to minimize the work.

```
List<CourseListing> result = sf.forList(courseListing).filter().p("Number").eq().val("TRN-001").toList();
```

Comment: Hmmm, I can just modify my sql and use 'group by name' and I'd get similar results. What I really need is the products to be transferred into one big string listing all the products in that one field.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem another way (by changing the way the List is created via the SQL result set instead). This is still an interesting question though, and I agree that I should use a HashMap. Thanks for the help.

Here's the code in case anyone has a similar problem:

```
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rset = null;

        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * FROM CourseProduct "
                + "INNER JOIN Course "
                + "ON CourseProduct.number=Course.number "
                + "inner join Product "
                + "on CourseProduct.P_ID=Product.P_ID "
                + "WHERE "
                + "(superProduct = ? or ? ='') "
                + "and (product = ? or ? ='') "
                + "and (location = ? or ? ='') "
                + "and (type = ? or ? ='') "
                + "and (category = ? or ? ='') "
                + "order by Course.number asc");

        pstmt.setString(1, superProduct);
        pstmt.setString(2, superProduct);
        pstmt.setString(3, product);
        pstmt.setString(4, product);
        pstmt.setString(5, location);
        pstmt.setString(6, location);
        pstmt.setString(7, type);
        pstmt.setString(8, type);
        pstmt.setString(9, category);
        pstmt.setString(10, category);


        rset = pstmt.executeQuery();

        String tempString = " ";

        String tempNumber1=null, tempNumber2 = null;

        while (rset.next()) {
            // here we go
            tempNumber1 = rset.getString("number");

             tempString+=", "+rset.getString("product");

            if (tempNumber1 == null ? tempNumber2 == null : tempNumber1.equals(tempNumber2)) {

               courseListing.remove(courseListing.size()-1);

                courseListing.add(new CourseListing(
                        rset.getDouble("price"),
                        rset.getString("number"),
                        rset.getString("name"),
                        rset.getString("location"),
                        rset.getString("unit"),
                        rset.getString("duration"),
                        rset.getString("type"),
                        rset.getString("role"),
                        rset.getString("category"),
                        rset.getString("maxNumStudents"),
                        rset.getString("superProduct"),
                        rset.getString("subProduct"),
                        tempString));
            } 

            else {
                tempString=rset.getString("product");
                tempNumber2 = rset.getString("number");

                courseListing.add(new CourseListing(
                        rset.getDouble("price"),
                        tempNumber2,
                        rset.getString("name"),
                        rset.getString("location"),
                        rset.getString("unit"),
                        rset.getString("duration"),
                        rset.getString("type"),
                        rset.getString("role"),
                        rset.getString("category"),
                        rset.getString("maxNumStudents"),
                        rset.getString("superProduct"),
                        rset.getString("subProduct"),
                        tempString)); 

            } 
        }
```